# save data with Angular and Firebase

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm creating a Deckbuilder, i have this decks of cards and a data-storage.service to store and fetch the decks in Firebase.
i have a component deck-details that shows the details of a selected deck and allows to remove or add cards to the deck.
i'm trying to store the modified cards in the selected deck in firebase

this is the data-storage service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DataStorageService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private deckService: DeckService) {}

  storeDecks() {
    const decks = this.deckService.getDecks();
    this.http
      .put("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks.json", decks)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log("stored");
      });
  }
  fetchDecks() {
    return this.http
      .get<Deck[]>("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks.json")
      .subscribe((decks) => {
        decks
          ? this.deckService.setDecks(decks)
          : this.deckService.setDecks([]);
        console.log("fetching", decks);
      });
  }
  storeCards(i: number, cards: Card[]){
    this.http
    .put("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/" + i + "/deckCards", cards)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("cards stored");
    });
  }
}
```

storeDecks and fetchDecks work, but i have a problem with storeCards function called in the deck-details component in the onCardsEdit() function.
this is the deck-detail component

```
import { Card } from "./../../card/card.model";
import { Deck } from "./../../deck/deck.model";
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { DeckService } from "src/app/deck/deck.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { DataStorageService } from 'src/app/shared/data-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-deck-details",
  templateUrl: "./deck-details.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./deck-details.component.scss"],
})
export class DeckDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  paramsSubscription: Subscription;
  id: number;
  decks: Deck[];
  deck: Deck;

  constructor(
    private deckService: DeckService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataStorageService: DataStorageService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.decks = this.deckService.getDecks();
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params["id"];
      this.deck = this.decks.find((deck) => deck.id === this.id);
    });

  }

  onDeleteCard(i){
    this.deckService.deleteCard(this.deck, this.deck.deckCards[i])
  }
  onCardsEdit(){
    this.dataStorageService.storeCards(this.decks.indexOf(this.deck), this.deck.deckCards)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.paramsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

when i try to store the cards i get these 3 errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/1/deckCards' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
>
> PUT https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/1/deckCards net::ERR_FAILED
>
> core.js:5882 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/1/deckCards", ok: false, …}

Comment: Did you already search for the error messages? The CORS policy one pops up fairly regularly, so there's likely a good explanation of why you get it, and how to address it. If I recall correctly it's because you forgot to add `.json` to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interact with the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database, your URLs must end with `.json`. Without that, you're trying to access the Firebase console, which returns a cross-origin error when you do.

So the code should look something like:

```
this.http
    .put("https://ang-cards.firebaseio.com/decks/" + i + "/deckCards.json", cards)
    ...
```